# How can return on current culture who user used in PC

Tags: c#, wpf, cultureinfo, culture

I read csv file and columns is separate with comma. In some cultures the separator is point, and for this reason I decide to change current culture to "en-US", who use comma for separator. But after when I finish with some operation I need return in the culture who user used. But I can't.

How can return current culture who user used?

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
// do something 
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var a = ci.DisplayName;
```

Is continue to be "en-US"

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly. Do you wanna return `"en-US"` as a `string`? Just return `ci.Name`?

Comment: You probably dont want to change current culture just to read a csv-file as this could have unwanted side-effects. You should change your code that access the csv to use its own cultureinfo and use the method overloads that accept IFormatProvider instead.

Comment: I save the culture before change and now is working good. With two row code is working in this way what I want. Thanks for the helping for Dmitry Bychenko and Dion V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Save your current culture;
var myCurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

//Adjust the culture
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

//Set it back
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = myCurrentCulture;

CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var a = ci.DisplayName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just *save* and then *restore*:

```
var saved = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

try {
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
  // do something 
finally {
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = saved;
}
```

Another (a bit *exotic*) possibity is to hide the logic in specially designed class:

```
public sealed class CurrentCulture: IDisposable {
  private CultureInfo m_Saved;

  public CurrentCulture(CultureInfo info) {
    //TODO: validate info
    m_Saved = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
  }

  public CurrentCulture(String name) :
    this(new CultureInfo(name)) {
  }

  public void Dispose() {
    if (m_Saved != null) {
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = m_Saved;
      m_Saved = null;
    }
  }
}

...

using (var c = new CurrentCulture("en-US")) {
  // do something 
}
```

Comment: Well this is awkward. May I ask why you put `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");` in a `try` block? It only throws `ArgumentNullException`, but is that something you want to catch?

Comment: @Dion V.: technically, you can put `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");`*out* of `try`, it's just a my habiit: whatever happens (e.g. `"en-US"` *not found*) I want to be sure that  `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = saved;` will be called and thus culture will be restored.

Comment: Forgot about the `finally` part, spot on.